# My border-radius not working in all four corners

Tags: html, css, border

[image: my broder radius]

I'm trying do my border-radius works in all four corners but ir dosent happen. Someone can help me?

my HTML:

```css
#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content .head_bg {
  border-color: #8cc63f;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content .head span {
  color: #fff;
}

#generic_table .generic_content {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content .head_bg {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 45px 1300px 20px 399px;
  position: absolute;
}

#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content .head {
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content .head span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="generic_table">
  <div class="generic_content">
    <div class="generic_head">
      <div class="generic_head_content">
        <div class="head_bg"></div>
        <div class="head">
          <span>AÇÕES</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what might be going on.

PS: I'm doing some testing and I believe my problem is with 'head_bg'.

Comment: for me your question is no clear, do you want to achieve a button like the image you posted?

Comment: Same question. When I run your code (although adding the generic_table div), it's working fine for me. I'm seeing rounded corners on all 4

Comment: @Sven can you show me how you do it?

Comment: I added a div wrapper to your code example because what you provided was insufficient as none of the rules you posted were being applied. Now we can see them. Update your question as needed.

Comment: @Patrick, not sure what you mean. I am just testing exactly your code and it shows me 4 rounded corners.

Comment: Browser is parsing `border-radius: 25px;` correctly on all four corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding here is causing an issue (`div class="head"`). If padding-top is 0 the corners are rounded better. As the padding increases, that 1 corner gets squared-off more.

```
#generic_table .generic_content .generic_head .generic_head_content .head {
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue but for me only

```
overflow: auto;
```

was enough